# How to uninstall or remove reddit script?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, uninstall, software-uninstall

I was experimenting and I downloaded and installed (i guess) the reddit install script.
After that I saw that it was advised to do it in a Virtualbox. so, I want to remove it.

How can I do it? 
Has it changed anything in my computer?

thanks!

Comment: If you provide the link that you followed to install it, then it would be easier to understand your situation. You can post the link here..

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it via terminal such as sudo apt-get reddit-script you can remove it by typing in the command sudo apt-remove reddit-script. If you didnt install it that way try it anyway. Also with a program you installed there is a uninstaller